# What is the meaning of <.before ...>?

Tags: raku

In Perl 6, what is the meaning of `<.before ... >` in a regex?
It seems to mean the same as `<?before ... >`:

```
my $str = "Hello";
$str ~~ /<alpha> <?before 'o'>/;
say $/;
$str ~~ /<alpha> <.before 'o'>/;
say $/;
```

**Output**:

```
｢l｣
 alpha => ｢l｣
｢l｣
 alpha => ｢l｣
```

I would like to clarify this, because I saw some code that used `<.before ...>` and I was not sure what it was suppose to mean. It could be illegal syntax, or it could mean negative lookahead `<!before ...>` or positive lookahead `<?before ...>` or something else. I know that I can make a rule like `<alpha>` non-capturing by putting a dot in front of it `<.alpha>`, but it does not make sense for me for lookaheads since they are always non-capturing. In any case, it should then be written `<.?before ... >` or `<.!before ... >` to distinguish between positive and negative lookahead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<.before ...>` is the same as `<?before ...>`, though less obvious a look-ahead (which is why I recommend using the `<?before ...>` form).

Basically, `<?anything>` turns `anything` into a positive look-ahead, and `<.anything>` is a non-capturing subrule call. Since `before` is already a look-ahead, and neither form captures, they behave the same.